# F# client, IIS7, and WCF

Tags: wcf, f#, iis-7

I am trying to learn a bit of F# and thought I would start by creating a "data layer" for my client applications.

I currently have a very large visual studio client solution in C# that accesses a PostgreSQL database via WCF services (hosted in IIS7). I have grown quite spoiled by the "Add Service Reference" ability of WCF to create proxy clients and DTO's.

I am new to F#. Is there any similar process of automatically creating client DTO's and proxies in an F# project for WCF services? And if not, what would be the recommended process of creating F# types for access to the WCF services?

Any starting point would be helpful, as most of the Googled references are very old.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the WSDL type provider

https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/wsdl.html